# PHP Authentication with monthly billing

Tags: php, membership, billing, authentication

A startup client of mine is looking to launch a SaaS with multiple features/options that would increase/decrease monthly billing.

The simplest solution would be best.

Comment: What is your question specifically about? The design, best implementation idea?

Comment: What's your question? Are you looking for an out-of-the-box solution? A payment gateway? Tips on writing your own system?

Comment: They want to increase bills? Send me their address and I'll send them a bill every month! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for a third-party system to hook into, [Spreedly](https://spreedly.com/) looks pretty promising.

Comment: This seems to be exactly what i was looking for.  Sorry my question was a little hard to read.  I'm on site with one client trying to post without being seen for another.

Answer (score 1):

I would check on each login when was the last time the user paid, if it's more than a month ago, you make the user go to a payment page (paypal, a cgi from your client's bank...) and have him pay the amount you calculated from the options he uses this last month.

Maybe a simpler solution is to have the user paying "at the beginning" instead : each month he choose what options/features he will use during the next month and then pay for that.